# Terraform parameterizing block

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, hcl

I am creating a module on top of the [azurerm_app_service](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service). I don't want to grow the input variable list to collect all the possible values for the bigger blocks eg [`site_config`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service#site_config).

```
variable var1{}
variable var2{}
..
..
..
variable varN{}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "example" {
  name                = "example-app-service"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id

    site_config {
        key1 = var.var1
        key2 = var.var2
        ...
        ...
        keyN = var.varN
        
      }

  app_settings = {
    "SOME_KEY" = "some-value"
  }
}
```

I want to parametrize the entire block itself.

something like this

```
variable var_block{
  type = map()
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "example" {
  name                = "example-app-service"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id

      site_config {
        var.var_block   
      }

  app_settings = {
    "SOME_KEY" = "some-value"
  }
}
```

Looking for something like **kwargs in the python world.

Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: hello @user1960109, site_config has list of specified parameters , if you are creating a new parameter then it will error out with error that this parameter is not expected here .

Comment: As an extension to the above comment, you would then need the variable to be type `object` with optional values, which would become messy. If `site_config` was an argument instead of a block then this would be much more feasible, but presumably multiple `site_config` can be declared.

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT I totally agree that we could get the error as unexpected params not available. The assumption here is that consumers of these modules will be knowing what are possible values to be supplied. In that scenario, do we have any option to simplify this?

Comment: @MattSchuchard Definitely adding object type is difficult to manage and messy. Unfortunately AzureRM comes with site_config as block and not argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic block to manage all the values from only one point, for instance, in my example you can see an example using a local variable, other than that, you can use variables to handle and manage them.

Before you start, you must use `for_each` and, also `lookup` to find and validate the values into the variable, if the key isn't finding it a null is returned, this behavior it's really useful for optional parameters.

```
locals {
    site_configs = [
        {
            acr_use_managed_identity_credentials = "value1"
            acr_user_managed_identity_client_id = "value1"
            always_on = "value1"
            app_command_line = "value1"
            cors = "value1"
        },
        {
            acr_use_managed_identity_credentials = "value2"
            acr_user_managed_identity_client_id = "value2"
            always_on = "value2"
            app_command_line = "value2"
            cors = "value2"
        }
    ]
}


resource "azurerm_app_service" "example" {
  name                = var.variable_here
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id

  dynamic "syte_config" {
      for_each = local.syte_configs
      content {
          lookup(syte_config.value, "acr_use_managed_identity_credentials", null)
          lookup(syte_config.value, "acr_user_managed_identity_client_id", null)
          lookup(syte_config.value, "always_on", null)
          lookup(syte_config.value, "app_command_line", null)
          lookup(syte_config.value, "cors", null)
      }
  }

  app_settings = {
    "SOME_KEY" = "some-value"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I want to make the keys inside the attribute also as dynamic. Something like this ```  dynamic "site_config" {
    for_each = var.site_config
    content {
      each.key = each.value
    }
}```

Comment: Great, you can do that making a for_each also for the resource, but sounds a bit specific, for sure, you have to test it until you get the expected outcome

Comment: No, what i mentioned doesn't work. I just gave for reference.